# Two desktop sessions after fresh install of Debian 12

Tags: debian, x11, kde, wayland

I successfully installed Debian 12 (with KDE Plasma DE) on my PC and the first time logging into the desktop environment, I noticed there are two desktop sessions for me to pick from:

1. Plasma (Wayland)
2. Plasma (X11)

[image]

By default, Wayland is used and when I tried to login using my username and pw, I was not able to even though my password is 100% correct.  However, when I switch the session from Wayland to X11, I was able to successfully login.

My questions are:

1. Since this is a fresh install of Debian 12, why are there two desktop sessions (wayland and x11)?
2. Are they interdependent? Can I remove Wayland? Thanks!